# How to generate a full html report with nCover command line

Tags: ncover

I have nCover 4.5 version,
I am trying to export the coverage report to html
But once I am sending it to someone else by email, he is not able to open the other webpages since it is linked to my localhost 127.0.0.0 ip. How can I export the full html report independently to my localhost.
I am using command line:

```
C:\Users\aaa>ncover report --project=MyProj --execution=08/17/2015
```

--file=c:\MyFile.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer:
Only in nCover version 5, it is possible to generate a full html report.

http://www.ncover.com/blog/sharing-code-coverage-results-ncover-code-central/

see "The Detailed Report" section